# Change RecyclerView.ItemDecoration color per item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a custom item decorator for my recyclerview and it works fine.

**MyItemDecorationTest.java**

```
public class MyItemDecorationTest extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration{

    private Paint paint;
    private final static int OFFSET = 8;

    public MyItemDecorationTest(Paint paint){
        this.paint = paint;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.set(OFFSET, OFFSET, OFFSET, OFFSET);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onDraw(c, parent, state);

        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = parent.getLayoutManager();

        for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++){
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            c.drawRoundRect(layoutManager.getDecoratedLeft(child) + OFFSET,
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedTop(child) + OFFSET,
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedRight(child) - OFFSET,
                    layoutManager.getDecoratedBottom(child) - OFFSET, 2, 2, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I include it in my activity:

```
RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new MyItemDecorationTest(getPaint(getResources().getColor(R.color.block_blue)));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

And this is my method to set the paint.

```
public Paint getPaint(int color){
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    return paint;
}
```

This is the render:

[image: item decoration example]

Now I want to change the color of the decorator per item. That means for instance change the blue color of the second item with red. And this is what I expect to have:

[image: desire state]

Is there any way to change decoration color on a per item basis using RecyclerView.ItemDecoration?

Comment: You can always do this inside ViewHolder. But well, you can change the color in your paint object as you want `paintLightBlue.setColor(rgb(...))`. And you can replace your `rgb(String)` method with `Color.parse`. Also, don't create a new `RectF` inside `onDraw`, it will waste a lot of memory

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sourabh. Please can you tell me how I can do this inside ViewHolder?

Comment: I updated the post accordingly to what you said about `RectF`  inside `onDraw` and paint color. But I'm still not able to see how I can change the paint color for each item.

Comment: Before `c.drawRoundRect` change color of `paint`.

Comment: Excuse me but maybe I didn't ask the question clearly. Let's say that I have 10 items on my recyclerView, and I want all of them with 10 different colors. What. The color need to be specific to the item. How can I change the color of the decoration dynamically for all those items but outside of the ItemDecoration Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using ItemDecoration for changing the color of your items, you should consider drawing the borders directly in the layout and change the color of the layout at runtime.

You can do for instance:

**corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#07AFF2" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Add it into your drawable folder. your layout.xml file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bloc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/corner">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Element" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

- override `getItemViewType(int position)` to return different view types,
- provide different layouts for different view types,
- override `onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` to inflate different layouts,
- provide drawables in different colors,
- pass all the drawables to your `ItemDecoration` in its constructor,
- override `onDraw(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)` to select correct drawable for each view type.

[My example with different colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDQEV.png)

I also tried changing color programmatically but it looks like it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

From your RecyclerView Adapter's 'onBindViewHolder' method, you can pass the current item position to your Viewholder and update the item to the desired color from there.

Comment: Is there any instruction I can use to change the `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` paint color in `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: Instead of painting through Recyclerview, why don't you paint the item you inflate on to the Recyclerview directly, which is what I was pointing to.

Comment: The real problem is that the color is defined at the construction of the itemdecoration object. And it's a method related to the recycler view itself, not to his elements